# Automatically detect when I typed "vi" but meant "cd"?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, cd-command

About 5 times a day, I type "vi" when I meant "cd", and end up opening a directory in vi.  It's making me NUTS.  It seems like there should be a way to detect when I type in "vi + directory" and automatically change it to "cd + directory".  Thoughts?

Comment: I gave an alternative that you may find interresting as well ^^ (one that let you correct the source of the problem, while avoiding getting irritated until then ^^)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073807/how-to-stop-vim-from-creating-opening-a-new-file

Comment: It also frustrated me a lot, till I discovered that you can use Enter and arrows to navigate to the file inside the folder. When you click Enter while being on it it opens.

Comment: With only a small amount of facetiousness: change to zsh. Set it up so that when you type a directory name it changes into that directory. Use suffix aliases so that when you type *.sh, *.c, *.config whatever it opens the relevant file in vi. The caveat here is of course that you may find yourself omitting "vi" or "cd" in an unfamiliar shell.

Comment: How does this happen?

Comment: @JFA, those are the two commands I use most often, so sometimes I instinctively type one when I meant the other....

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With the assumption that you call `vi` with the directory as the last argument:

```
vi() {
    if [[ -d ${!#} ]]; then
        cd "$@"
    else 
        command vi "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: @Alex I guess this is both perfect for the rare cases you typed "vi" incorrectly instead of "cd", while at the same time teach you to always type "vi" now ;) [ie, I hope you don't often have to use another server/machine where that function will not be there to save you stress...]  [+1 for that answer, though, it's what I wanted to answer as well, except I'd just test for "${1}" [and then cd "${1}"] instead of "${!#}" ...]

Comment: @OlivierDulac Agreed -- similarly dangerous is aliasing `rm` to `rm -i`, which is the default in many distributions. I generally think that the best way to solve problems is to solve the user rather than to work around them.

Comment: @ChrisDown: PEBKAC ^^  So true... But I still alias `rm`(and mv and cp) to `rm -i` though, as it saved me much troubles in the past ;) [Edit: no, I do not alias cp and mv to `rm -i` ;) ]

Comment: This made me think of an alternative answer ^^

Comment: @OlivierDulac aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` might have saved you some trouble in the past but might (and probably will) get you in much more trouble in the future ...

Comment: This is great, I'll just point out for any future readers to make sure you change vi to vim; this killed my syntax highlighting, visual mode, etc., until I  caught the problem.

Comment: @Alex Well, you did say `vi` in the question...

Comment: @ChrisDown : I have two doubts regarding this. (1) What does ${!#} mean? (2) Is it necessary to use `command` with `vi` here?

Comment: @crisron: `${!#}` indirectly references the final argument, and `command` is only necessary to avoid function recursion in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from @ChrisDown answer, here is another approach: bypass directories

With this approach, you can :

```
vi ./*
```

and it will start vi on all the files in the current directory even if it contains subdirs, bypassing those subdirs

```
vi() {
  for arg do
    [ -d "$arg" ] || set -- "$@" "$arg"
    shift
  done
  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && command vi "$@"
}
```

This one just do vi, on any argument that are not directories... Hence it won't teach you to use "vi" for "cd" ;)

And it will not call vi if you just did:  vi somedirectory (ie, mistyped vi instead of cd).
But it will not cd there automatically then, so you still remember you have to type cd ^^

I used a "compatible" way to change the arguments lists, so that it's portable to many platforms.

Comment: note: `command something` : starts the "something" command (ie, the first occurence of "something" found using $PATH) instead of any alias OR function named "something".  `\something` would only bypasses the alias, but would still the function if it existed (and here, that would mean the function "vi" would call itself, and loop).

Comment: @ChrisDown: we are talking an aid to a user, which I hope won't try to hack himself ^^ . And that eval is to set a new set of arguments (set -- ... ), so it's less dangerous in itself

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: thanks for the edit! I tried to write it that way, but I was worried about looping infinitely [I trust you it won't loop, though!. The 'for arg' is being evaluated before the inner treatment starts, and therefore its "$@" list is 'saved' and iterated over, and not changed even though the inner treatment changes "$@" ?]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to stop using `cd` altogether. Put `shopt -s autocd` in your `.bashrc` or `setopt autocd` in your `.zshrc`. Then to change to a different directory, type the directory name, without any command.

Don't forget to type `vi` if you want to edit a file.

If you really want a single command to either change to a directory or edit a file, you can make it a function:

```
vi () {
  if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ -d "$1" ]; then
    cd -- "$1"
  else
    command vi "$@"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Use alias feature in Unix. Once you alias cd to vi, the problem will be resolved.

Comment: ...this would mean that one cannot use `vi` without manually overriding the alias, which seems highly undesirable.

Comment: This answer comes across as slightly trollish.  It *does* answer the original question, as the OP did not specify they ever needed vi on a file.  The answer, although somewhat fun, is certainly not useful.

Comment: @ChrisDown Or this would teach you to use the proper `vim` instead.

Comment: @Kevin vim is not more "proper" than vi -- on many systems, vi is all that is available.

Comment: @ChrisDown I'd argue it's better to know what to expect. If you expect to use vim features, use `vim`. If it's not available, use `vi` and expect the more limited feature set.